# Spring security saml extension usable for IDP implementation

Tags: spring, saml, opensaml

Is the Spring security saml extension usable for implementing the IDP side of a SAML connection?

I can find a lot of example around the implementation of the SP side of SAML, but at the IDP side only opensaml seems to be an option if I want to make a custom java solution.

Am I correct? Or do I miss some documentation on the Spring security saml extension

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Spring security SAML extension is a SAMLv2 Service Provider implementation only.